# Usage od UnmapProperty, UnmapMember, UnmapField

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The usage of these statements is not clear for me.
 I give the following example

```
if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(Province)))
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Province>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.SetIdMember(
            cm.GetMemberMap(c =>
            c.ProvinceId).SetIdGenerator(UniqueIdGenerator.Instance));
            cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.CountryId);
            cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.EloqueraId);
            cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.UpdateMode);
        });
}
```

The last 2 properties have no private fields, but the first (CountryId) has.
I have a feeling like, when using the UnmapProperty, the private field is not ignored and I should better use UnmapMember???

Can please someone explain more in depth how to handle these statements? Or give me a hint  where to find it?
Thank you

Comment: Looks like someone didn't want the ContryId, EloqueraId or UpdateMode properties of the in-memory class to be serialized and saved in the database.

Comment: let me say that a different way: What exactly is or does Unmapmember ??

Answer (score 0):

*UnmapMember* finds the *BsonMemberMap* corresponding to the *System.Reflection.MemberInfo* and removes the mapping for it.

Both *UnmapField* and *UnmapProperty* take just the field or property name, resolve it to a *System.Reflection.MemberInfo* and call *UnmapMember*

In a way, UnmapField and UnmapProperties are syntactic sugar for UnmapMember which do the reflection for you by filed or property string name.

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a class map you can either:

1. call MapMember for each member you want serialized
2. or call AutoMap and let it find the members automatically

If you want most of the members serialized, but not all of them, it is sometimes easier to call AutoMap and then unmap the members you **don't** want serialized (as opposed to calling MapMember for all the members you **do** want serialized).